# Why can't twitter read my files in the External Cache Directory?

Tags: android, twitter, xamarin, xamarin.android

I created an Android mobile with Xamarin Android. There is a feature inside that app that can send an image to twitter. I tested this feature after downloading the app from the play store on the Samsung S7, the alcatel Pixi4 and my tablet (Galaxy Tab 2). My code creates a bitmap file in the external cachedirectory and requests twitter to read this file in order to have it attached to a tweet.

It works fine. However, I asked other people to test it (they also downloaded my app from the play store) and they told me the file is created in the cache directory but the bitmap picture is not attached to their tweets. It is also important to know that other apps that do that (such as long tweet) work on all devices:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.cbruegg.longtweet

I don't understand. Twitter, works on all devices. This has been checked. Apps (such as long tweet) can send a file to twitter to tweet this. This also works on all devices. Moreover, my app perfectly writes files to the cache directory. Works on all devices. In addition, my app is able to send a bitmap picture to twitter in order to tweet the picture. This works on my S7. But not on the S7 of my tester. I don't get it. Here is my code. Someway, I am doing something wrong. By the way, generating the tweets always works. It is just the case that the picture is not attached to the tweet when testing on the device of my tester.

Here is my code. Please let me know how I should improved it.

```
public bool TweetImage(Bitmap imageToTweet)
{
    var messageIntent = context.FindMessageIntent(this.twitterConstants.PackageName);
    if (messageIntent == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    string outputFileBMP = SaveBitmap(imageToTweet);
    context.Tweet(messageIntent, outputFileBMP, this.twitterConstants.DefaultTwitterText, this.twitterConstants.ChooserMessage);
    return true;
}

private string SaveBitmap(Bitmap imageToTweet)
{
    string outputFileBMP = System.IO.Path.Combine(context.ExternalCacheDir.Path, System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".bmp");
    using (var outputFileStream = System.IO.File.Create(outputFileBMP))
    {
        imageToTweet.Compress(Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, outputFileStream);
    }
    return outputFileBMP;
}
```

and

```
public static Intent FindMessageIntent(this ContextWrapper contextWrapper, params string[] packageNames)
{
    Intent wantedIntent = new Intent();
    wantedIntent.SetType("text/plain");

    var resolveInfos = contextWrapper.PackageManager.QueryIntentActivities(wantedIntent, PackageInfoFlags.MatchDefaultOnly);

    var result =  (from r in resolveInfos
                   from p in packageNames
                   where p == r.ActivityInfo.PackageName
                   select p).FirstOrDefault();

    if (result != null)
    {
        wantedIntent.SetPackage(result);
        return wantedIntent;
    }
    return null;
}
```

and

```
public static void Tweet(this ContextWrapper contextWrapper, Intent messageIntent, string filePath = null, string message = null, string chooserMessage = null)
{
    if (filePath != null)
    {
        using (var file = new Java.IO.File(filePath))
        {
            messageIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file));
        }
    }
    if (message != null)
    {
        messageIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, message);
    }

    if (chooserMessage != null)
    {
        using (var chooser = Intent.CreateChooser(messageIntent, chooserMessage))
        {
            contextWrapper.StartActivity(chooser);
        }
        return;
    }
    contextWrapper.StartActivity(messageIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using the external cache directory, you should always make sure it exists before using it. From the Android documentation:

> The external storage may be unavailable—such as when the user has mounted the storage to a PC or has removed the SD card that provides the external storage—you should always verify that the volume is available before accessing it. You can query the external storage state by calling getExternalStorageState(). If the returned state is equal to MEDIA_MOUNTED, then you can read and write your files.

S7 supports MicroSD cards so maybe this is the case with your tester?

Also, Long Tweet does the image storing and sharing slightly differently than you. Here are the differences:

1. They store the generated bitmap to the internal cache directory (CacheDir instead of ExternalCacheDir).
2. They set the read and write permissions (Readable and Executable properties of the File object) to the resulting file and directory, so that other apps can access the file when they have the full path.

For the record, here's the Java code for how they set up the intent:

```
public static void intentImage(Context context, File file, String intentAction)
{
    file.getParentFile().getParentFile().setExecutable(true, false);
    file.getParentFile().setExecutable(true, false);
    file.getParentFile().getParentFile().setReadable(true, false);
    file.getParentFile().setReadable(true, false);
    file.setReadable(true, false);
    file.setExecutable(true, false);

    String fileStr = "file://" + file.toString();

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(intentAction);

    if (intentAction == "android.intent.action.SEND") 
    {
        intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.STREAM", Uri.parse(fileStr));
        intent.setType("image/" + fileStr.substring(fileStr.lastIndexOf(".") + 1));
    } 

    else 
    {
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(fileStr), "image/" + fileStr.substring(fileStr.lastIndexOf(".") + 1));
    }

    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

I would start by utilizing the internal cache directory and setting the correct permissions to the file generated (possibly also the parent folder).